# Delay between OpenCL kernel being queued and starting to run on ATI cards

Tags: opencl

I have recently moved an OpenCL application from a NVIDIA GPU to a Radeon HD 6320 Fusion running on Ubuntu 12.04, and it is unexpectedly running significantly slower.

My program copies a very large data structure on setup to the GPU (this data structure is never read or accessed by the CPU again), and then it:

1. Queues several kernels and a read buffer (to copy a very small data structure back to main memory).
2. Calls clFinish to wait for the kernels and the read buffer to complete
3. This continually repeats, with occasionally some extra data copied depending on what information is returned by the read buffer (this means the read buffer has to complete before the next round of kernels can be added to the queue).

After profiling both GPUs, the delay on the ATI GPU seems to be entirely from the first kernel being being added to the queue (CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED) to the first kernel starting execution (CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START). On the NVIDIA GPU, this takes a few microseconds each iteration. On the ATI GPU, this takes around 20ms each iteration, which is far too long for my use.

Is there any reason why I could be getting this large delay?

Comment: Did you tryed different queues?

Answer (score 1):

Its a known issue in amd platforms. Check this forum link https://community.amd.com/thread/159060
Hopefully it is/will be fixed

Comment: your forum link is stale-tastic, and no title or anything for us to search for instead...

Comment: Updated the link

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things, are you running any other GPU programs that may need to complete so that the scheduler can free up some time for you?

The problem with this is that the OpenCL specification doesn't define the possible wait time. There is no requirement on timing from queueing a kernel to it's execution only that at some point it will execute. I would probably post on the ATI OpenCL boards, the developers there are well up on this subject and can probably give you an answer.